# Measuring an entangled quantum state

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, textbook-and-exercises

[image: exercise]

I have this exercise to solve, but I can't figure out how to proceed.

First, I don't think the state proposed is valid (the probabilities don't sum up to 1).
'Secondly, given that it should be an entangled state, is it possible to do the measurement using the single operator?

I'm having trouble with the dimensions of the matrices/vectors.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE. Where is this from? (What textbook?)

Comment: @MarkSpinelli it's an exercise my professor professor of Quatum Information Science proposed, I don't know if he took it from some textbook unfortunately

Comment: The projector operator in the exercise is just for one qubit, and it is associated to a 2×2 matrix. Maybe your professor want you measure just one qubit?! If we assume the state is entangled, just one measure should be sufficient. But I'm not sure the state is entangled in the basis of the projector operators

Comment: the normalisation is indeed wrong here. They might have meant to write $\sqrt3$ for the first coefficient instead